Guarantee consumer order message into kafka with one topic and multiple producers
I'm looking to scale my Kafka producers by having two or three instances of the same producer sending events to Kafka. However, due to network failures or other issues, some events might be produced out of order. Using keys is not a solution because all events will be stored in the same topic and partition.
For example:
A user updates their name from A to B on their profile page.
Producer 1 receives the message but takes 30 seconds to process it.
The user refreshes the page and changes their name from A to C.
Producer 2 receives this second message and sends it to Kafka immediately.
Producer 1 finishes processing the first message and then sends it to Kafka.
Instead of having the events in the topic as B and C, they are stored as C and B.
I've read (https://aiven.io/blog/kafka-real-ordering) that you cannot control this behavior at the producer level and might need to control the order at the consumer level by reading a batch of messages and reordering them before processing. However, this approach seems complex and might lead to another problem: the message you need to reorder might not be in the buffer due to its late arrival.
Any ideas or examples on how to handle this issue?
I´m using Kafka 3 and Spring Boot 3!

It sounds like you need to implement a Command Pattern. One topic, with one partition. This way a consumer on that topic (even if it is multiple instances in the same group) is always going to consume commands from that partition in the order they are placed onto the topic. It won't consume the next command until it is done with the current one. This way your long process will block the rest of new data until it is done with the current one.

Not exactly! My problem is that events can be out of order on the consumer side because Kafka stores events in the order they arrived, not in the order they were created.

What I meant is to not execute logic immediately before pushing to Kafka topic. But have an intermediate topic for commands and process those command in a single-threaded consumer. Then when this consumer is done with the process it can push to then data topic. Another name of the pattern is "Work Queue": https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/designing-distributed-systems/9781491983638/ch10.html

Sure, here's the corrected phrase:
I understand your point! However, the challenge lies in the 'time window' for processing. If I consider a 10-second time window (example), all events within these 10 seconds will be ordered in ascending order. However, the event I want to reorder may arrive late, at the 15-second mark.

So, what you mean even if that event comes later you still would like to process that one first, even if you have older events? That's probably not how Apache Kafka works. It is only-append broker. There is no way to reorder them in the topic.

If I cannot reorder into topic how reorder using another approach? Is there any way differing from time windows? I´ve found this article that lookes like what I want https://aiven.io/blog/kafka-real-ordering By the way your comments are great :D

I know another approach called Resequencer, but I’m not sure if there are any other implementation rather than Spring Integration: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/resequencer.html
